# Is all traffic routed through Tor when using TBB?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, encryption

Consider a computer connected to the Tor network through the Tor Browser Bundle: my question is does the whole internet traffic go through the Tor network like windows update, kaspersky update, vlc update or if I'm watching a video on YouTube in Tor browser does only that video data traffic get encrypted?.

Answer (score 2):

When running the Tor Browser, **only the Tor Browser connects through the Tor network**. Other applications are not affected and will connect in the same way they always do.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using special system like Whonix or Tails, then only the Tor Browser connects through Tor.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **NO**. Tor is **not** a routing(i.e. OSI Layer 2 or 3) software, and TBB is *just* a browser. Tor itself opens a SOCKS proxy service for Layer 3+, and TransPort, i.e. transparent proxy, for Layer 3 alone. You *can* route all the traffic through Tor, but **you need to elaborate by yourself** a component to utilize tor's service ports: usually you use a firewall + TransPort for tasks like this. That's actually why you can configure which kind of packet forwarding format it will expect ( via `TransProxyType` directive in torrc)